# How to localize string interpolation for notification message localizedUserNotificationString?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

Tried to add a number inside a localized string with `localizedUserNotificationString` function. However, passing the argument into the function would cause a server connection error despite its a local notification. Replacing the arguments with a `nil` can solve the issue though.

```
// the real type of day is Int OR 
let day = getDay()

// Same error with both Int and CVarArg type
let day = getDay() as CVarArg 


content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(
    forKey: "day %@",
    arguments: [day]
)
```

Inside Localizable.strings,

```
"day %@" = "Day %@";
```

The error is

```
APP_NAME[60875:8076287] [Connections] [www.domain.APP_NAME] Adding notification request failed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service on pid 40685 named com.apple.usernotifications.usernotificationservice" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service on pid 40685 named com.apple.usernotifications.usernotificationservice}
ERROR:setupNotification Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.
```

Comment: What is real type of `day`?

Comment: @Asperi it is an Int

Comment: Did you try to pass it in arguments explicitly as Int instead of CVarArg?

Comment: Yes, the error is the same; before I changed to CVarArg;

Comment: Maybe the problem is using "%@“ within the key. Did you try using instead something like "day" = "Day %@„;?

Comment: Tried it before I add it there @Reinhard

Comment: I did try same as you and for me it works. @Metropolis ould you try to do same thing only with "hello world" app.

Comment: I have the same problem. Specifically I can't make it work when passing arguments. I have tried `NSNumber` and it didn't help either.